# How to create deep copy of BoudStatement of datastax java driver?

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Is there a way to bind only few named variables of prepared statement and create a partial bound statement and then later create multiple bound statements out of it with filling in remaining named variables (from a list for example)?

```
p = session.prepare("select a from b where c=? AND d=?")
bound = p.bind("c", 1)

l.map(v => bound.bind("d", l))
```

In last statement above, I would like to clone 'bound' every time so I can then use all bound statements in executeAsync.

Comment: Why don't you keep the prepared statement and the bind it at execute async. That's how the driver is meant to be used.

Comment: Bound statement is not thread safe.

Comment: Currently if I want to use executeAsync, looks like I must get new bound statement from prepared statement. If I were to do, l.map(v => bound.bind("d", l)) and executeAsync and then l1.map(v => bound.bind("d", l)) first batch of prepared statements could just have values from l2 as "d". My goal is to find a way to clone already partially bound statement.

Comment: also, keeping prepared statement is fine, I just don't want to bind 5 same values every time. In my case, only 1 variable in prepared statement is different when I am in this part of code.

Answer (score 1):

Just create prepared statement with predefined value:

```
p = session.prepare("select a from b where c=1 AND d=?")
l.map(v => bound.bind("d", l))
```

If you don't know value `c` at a compile time, create statement string dynamically:

```
c=1
p = session.prepare("select a from b where c=" + c + " AND d=?")
l.map(v => bound.bind("d", l))
```

And I don't see big problem with repeated binding of one value again and again. It's much more clear solution than clone bound statements.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know value '1' at compile time or when I am writing code. It is dynamic. I am just trying to avoid writing unnecessary binds again and again. From functional standpoint, it would be something like partial function.